# How to unit test an Update method with no return using xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have the follow method in the Repository class:

```
public async Task<int> Update(Entity entity)
{
    string sql = "UPDATE table SET name = @name";
    return await ExecuteAsync(sql, entity);
}
```

So, how can I do the unit test in this method, to ensure the record has been changed in the database ? I need to use mock or don't apply in this case ?

Comment: If you have to check in database then it is not a unit test. You are trying to do integration test. You can call the get method after calling update and check the values of they are updated in the database.

Comment: That was the certainty I needed. Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Right now your code looks like untestable. To make it testable in this method you pasted, ExecuteAsync needs to be a mockable method of some interface injected in your service under test. Then after execution of Update method, you can verify that ExecuteAsync was called with the statement  `"UPDATE table SET name = @name"`